# How do I instruct the kernel to use a USB keyboard and FB device as it's boot console?

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I'm guessing the answer to my question is in manipulating the kernel command line.  But with what arguments? (and does the kernel have it's own fonts to be used on a FB device?)

The host is a ARM9 based embedded system with a 1-bit LCD screen.

This is a prelude question to: [Naming a Frame buffer Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206368/how-does-my-framebuffer-driver-get-named-specified-from-the-command-line)

Comment: You would probably get a better answer for this question on superuser.com

Comment: Perhaps, but the follow-on questions are programming related ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use a USB keyboard if it's built with the USB HID and keyboard drivers. Passing `video=XXX` to the kernel tells it which framebuffer driver to load. See the kernel documentation in `Documentation/fb/` for more details.

Comment: So `vga=XXX` specifies /dev/fb0? or would I use `vga=/dev/fb`?

Comment: Sorry, that's for `vesafb` only. Answer updated.